# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

Tags: android, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

After updating to android studio 2.3 I got this error message.
I know it's just a hint as the app run normally but it's really strange.

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.1.1, 24.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.1 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0

[image]

my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.blankj:utilcode:1.3.6'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.15'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'

    provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.5'

    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.2@aar'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.1@aar') { transitive = true }
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.3.original@aar'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.CymChad:BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.MAXDeliveryNG:slideview:1.0.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: add this to your projectBuild.Gradle   subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.+"
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 913, accepted):

You can solve this with one of the following solutions:

### Update:

As of Android studio 3.0, it becomes much easier as it now shows a more helpful hint, so we only need to follow this hint.
for example:
[image: 1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BObtK.png)

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
> specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
> versions 27.0.2, 26.1.0. Examples include
> com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2 and
> com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0
>
> there are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
> are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
> compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
> the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
> targetSdkVersion.)

**Solution:**
Add explicitly the library with the old version but with a new version number.
in my case `com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0` so I need to add:

[build.gradle.kts](/questions/tagged/build.gradle.kts) (Kotlin Build Scripts)

```kotlin
implementation("com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2")
```

[build.gradle](/questions/tagged/build.gradle) (Groovy Build Scripts)

```
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2"
```

ie: Take the library from the second item, and implement it with the version number from the first.

Note: don't forget to press sync now so gradle can rebuild the dependency graph and see if there are any more conflicts.

**Explanation:**
you may be confused by the error message as don't use `customtabs` so how I have a conflict!!
well.. you didn't use it directly but one of your libraries uses an old version of `customtabs` internally, so you need to ask for it directly.

if you curious to know which of your libraries is responsible for the old version and maybe ask the author to update his lib, Run a Gradle dependency report, see the old answer to know how.

Note this

---

### Update:

As of gradle plugin version: 3.0 `compile` has been replaced by `implementation` or `api` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/3998402) for the difference.

hence use instead for mac, Linux and PowerShell:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath
```

or for windows cmd:

```
gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath
```

and search for the conflicted version.

For me, the error disappeared after removing `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0`

And only include `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0` as they are the only two play services that I use.

I think the `gms:play-services` depend on some old components of the support library, so we need to add them explicitly ourselves.

---

for AS 3.0 an older.

Run:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies <module-name>:dependencies --configuration implementation
```

Example:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration implementation
```

---

### Old answer:

inspired by [CommonsWare answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42582204/1843331):

Run a Gradle dependency report to see what your full tree of
dependencies is.

From there, you will see which one of your libraries are asking for a different version of the Android Support libraries.
For whatever it is asking for, you can ask for it directly with the
25.2.0 version or use Gradle's other conflict resolution approaches to get the same versions.

---

if someone knows a better way in the new gradle plugin please let me know.

Comment: `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0` supports SDK 14 and above, if you want to use below SDK 14, you need to use version `10.0.1` as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42315590/6248491

Comment: I added compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0' and updated compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.3.0' to compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.0'

Comment: i run that command to see the tree of dependencies, but i don't find any dependencies that has different version

Comment: @humazed noob question, where do I run the command in Android Studio?

Comment: in the terminal, but first, try to try the play-services thing

Comment: `com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0` from `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+`

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks this is insanity?  I just want admob and facebook, and they refuse to work together....

Comment: you cannot just copy paste content and present it as your own. Provide attribution please

Comment: Maybe one of `implemented` library contain the old version.

Comment: Hello, will this remove any potential runtime crash or just remove the compile time warning? thanks.

Comment: this removes any potential runtime relating to using different versions.

Comment: It may be helpful to point out that the `examples include` text in the error message shows actual examples from your own project, not vague general examples of the type of problem.  Take the library from the second item, and implement it with the version number from the first.

Comment: @BenjaminKershner I think it was clear from the context anyway I will edit my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: "maybe ask the author to update his lib" - Well, it's Google using old versions of their own libraries in the latest version of `play-services-location`. If we put in a bug report, they'll just wait three years and then close it as obsolete (without fixing it).

Comment: don't forget to add those line on above of error line

`implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2" `
`implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2"`

Comment: Adding library explicitly solved the issue thanks @humazed

Comment:  Adding explicitly the library with the old version but with a new version number, works for me.

Comment: In my opinion, when there's this many different answers and comments, as well as many upvotes, I feel it's a serious design/error diagnostic debugging flaw/message description not explained clearly in Android Studio. Succinctly the gist is, it's to "override the different versions of 'implemented' libraries, so all libraries are set to the maximum version used in any library mentioned in the list of 'implementation'."

Comment: follow this answer to see which library you need to change the version https://stackoverflow.com/a/39020547/8383332

Comment: @humazed, Thanks Buddy, Really appreciate your answer.

Comment: For people struggling with not knowing the project module (this legacy project has a really weird structure). This command helped me `./gradlew -q dependencies :dependencies` It looks on all your folders

Comment: perfect answer for me. It solves my problem. First change the version number of the older library  . . . in my case from com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 to com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2   then add it to your build.gradle dependency. Then make sure you sync it to take effect, and then problem will be solved. Thanks!

Comment: I run `./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath | grep --color -E -B 20 com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0` because I got overwhelmed by the bunch of dependencies in the output, this way I found the dependency I wanted to update with some context.

Comment: and then they ask me why i love people like you. Thank you!

Comment: Solving how to handle Android Studio breaking changes is how I spend my time now days. Developing business value stuff comes second. :D

Answer (score 202):

1. Go to `project/.idea/libraries` folder on your file system and see which libraries are different.
2. You will have to manually include these libraries with the same version in your `build.gradle` file.
3. Then, sync your project.

E.g.:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'

// Wrong library version found on 1st point
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
```

Comment: Good point. I never thought about taking a look which one actually was the wrong one. :S Thanks!

Comment: works when gradle automatic resolving method doesn't, thanks

Comment: in /Project Files/My project/.idea/libraries there are multiple support files with different version. Now how would I know which module or dependency is using this?

Comment: @SatpalYadav I've searched for the version not matching the newest one available (I use in my app). E.g. I use support:design:25.3.1 but material-dialogs uses support-v13:25.1.1. So I've added support-v13:25.3.1 and the error disappears.

Comment: Thats the best solution for me so far but how can I override newer libs?

Comment: Can I delete any of these libraries directly? I'm getting this error for play-services libraries I no longer use as I no longer use play services. Deleting cache and cleaning project has not gotten rid of a couple obsolete play-services libraries causing this conflict like 'Gradle__com_google_android_gms_play_services_auth_11_8_0.xml' Would just clicking on the offending libraries in the .idea/libraries and clicking 'delete' cause issues? There should be a way to do this more elegantly.

Answer (score 150):

### **For all cases, not just for these versions or libraries:**

Pay attention to the little information window that say something about the error, **it says the examples that you have to change and add**.

In this case:

> ***Found versions 25.1.1, 24.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.1 and
> com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0***

**Your**

> *com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.1*

***is version 25.1.1*, and your**

> *com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0*

***is version 24.0.0*, so you have to add the mediarouter with the same version:**

```
com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.1.1
```

And do that for every example that the little information window says, *in this case* **all the libraries that doesn't have the version 25.1.1.**

**You have to sync the gradle after you fix the indicated library to see the next library and package that you have to change.**

**IMPORTANT:**
If you are not explicitly using one or more specified libraries and it is giving you the error, **it means that is being used internally by another library, compile it explicitly anyway**.

You also can use another method to see the difference of the versions of all the libraries that you are actually compiling (like run a gradle dependency report or go to your libraries files), **the real objetive is compile all the libraries that you are using with the same version**.

Comment: thanks a ton, can you please explain what `support:mediarouter` exactly does ?

Comment: I think this is something you have pointed out that most of us have over looked. And ie- "Pay attention to the little information window that say something about the error....". Thank you, this is now given me a better understanding of what is really happening.

Answer (score 109):

**The best way to solve the problem is implement all 'com.android.support:...' suggested by Android Studio**

(Doesn't matter which support versions you are using – 27.1.1, 28.0.0 etc.)

Place the cursor to the error line e.g.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Android Studio will suggest you which 'com.android.support:...' is different version than
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Example

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.0, 27.0.2. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0

So add `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0`
 & `com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0`.
Now sync gradle file.

One by one try to implement all the suggested 'com.android.support:...' until there is no error in this line `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

In my case, I added

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

All these dependencies, it could be different for you.

Comment: i manually added both "implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0' " and " implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0' "   but the  
 "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' " is still underlined by red

Comment: @AAEM if you place the cursor on the error line it will show what are the dependencies you should add next. Please add all the dependencies to the same version and sync gradle file . If it show error again, follow the steps again until there is no error.

Answer (score 102):

Add this to the very end of your build.gradle (Module:app):

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '25.3.1'
        }
     }

   }
}
```

Make sure that you replace '25.3.1' with the version of the android support library that you want to use for all the dependencies , it should not be lower than your complile sdk version

than re sync gradle

Comment: This is what I needed, one of my dependencies was pulling in 27.0.1 somehow, even when I specified a lesser version at the top level. Out of curiosity, why do you exclude the "multidex"?

Comment: @ray Glad it helped, as per the documentation : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#multidex    the multidex is the only support library of the "com.android.support" group that use a different version identifier, on the link a provided it is version 1.0.0 , the most recent being 1.0.1 as you can see here : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: This has saved the day for me. But this android development is becoming even more fragmented every passing thay. People need to really check every support library perfectly before rolling it out. We don't always have the luxery of time to go through each new support release because we want to focus on building our products rather than going through all this. It's frustrating always

Comment: thank you so much for your solution, this relates to Groovy techniques and syntax, but in Android studio - gradle file, we can't show any suggestion (use Ctrl + Space) when write something like this. Do you know any plugin/tool to show suggestion when write Groovy code in gradle file, instead of copy/paste some code that we don't remember or understand.

Comment: @ThinkTwiceCodeOnce You can go here to learn more about groovy, and its inteliji plugins : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-groovy.html

Comment: thank you, I also found out a plug in called **Cucumber for Groovy** https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7213-cucumber-for-groovy that supports Code completion, method specification..., it helps alot when write some code in build.gradle file

Comment: This solved alot for me! Big thanks. The other solutions that include having to modify the third party dependencies was not an option.

Answer (score 54):

I had the exact same problem after updating to Android Studio 2.3

Adding this line to dependencies solved my problem:

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem after updating to Android Studio 2.3

Comment: For anyone using RenderScript, I set `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled false` this to false. And added compile `'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'` and error went away.

Comment: @LawGimenez And how should we use renderscript if we just disabled it?

Comment: looks like my problem is because of renderscript too, but what if i need renderscript for something else, not for customtabs?

Answer (score 46):

A) Run `gradle dependencies` or `./gradlew dependencies`

B) Look at your tree and figure out which of your dependencies is specifying a different support library version for a dependency you don't control.

I didn't realize that this warning also displays if the dependency is completely unused directly by your own code. In my case, Facebook specifies some support libs I wasn't using, you can see below most of those dependencies were overridden by my own specification of 25.2.0, denoted by the **-> X.X.X (*)** symbols. The card view and custom tabs libs weren't overridden by anyone, so I need to ask for 25.2.0 for those ones myself even though I don't use them.

```
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0 (*)
```

If gradle has already warned you and given you examples...

> Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.1
>   and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0

... it's even easier if you throw in some grep highlighting for the lower version since `gradle dependencies` can be quite verbose:

```
./gradlew dependencies | grep --color -E 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7|$'
```

Comment: From your explanation I understand that X.X.X -> Y.Y.Y (*)
means that X.X.X is overridden by Y.Y.Y, that is good to know

Comment: Literally the only valid answer.

Answer (score 32):

**Use variables**: Doing something like the following will make it easier for you to ensure that you use the same version with all libraries

```
dependencies {

    ext {
        support_library_version = '25.2.0'
        google_play_services_version = '10.2.0'
    }

    //#####################################################################
    //          Support Library
    //#####################################################################
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${support_library_version}"

    //#####################################################################
    //          Google Play Services
    //#####################################################################
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${google_play_services_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${google_play_services_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${google_play_services_version}"

    //#####################################################################
    //          Firebase
    //#####################################################################
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${google_play_services_version}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${google_play_services_version}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${google_play_services_version}"
```

More information on how Google suggests that you handle this versioning can be found in this article: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#top-level

Comment: thanks Dear Daniel F, I think this is the best way to avoid the version mixing problem.

Comment: Only one note please: As suggested in the link above, we should define this type variables in the TOP LEVEL GRADLE FILE
thanks again)

Answer (score 25):

just add this :

```
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0'
```

`Updated` for new SDK versions

```
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

Comment: It doesn't solve a problem that old library contains old SDK.

Answer (score 19):

As you already seen the all answers and comments above but this answer is to clear something which a new developer might not get easily.

**./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile**

The above line will save your life with no doubt but how to get the exact point from the result of above line.

When you get the all dependency chart or list from the above command then you have to search the conflicting version number which you are getting in your code. please see the below image.

[image]

in the above image you can see that **23.4.0** is creating the problem but this we not able to find in our gradle file. So now this version number(23.4.0) will save us. When we have this number then we will find this number in the result of above command result and directly import that dependency directly in our gradle file. Please see the below image to get the clear view.

[image]

you can clearly see that **com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0** and **com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0** are using the version which is creating the problem. Now just simply copy those line from dependency
list and explicitly use in our gradle file but with the updated version link

**implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0"**

Comment: Thank you! With newer versions of android studio, it should be switched to implementation instead of compile

Comment: Yes you are right @AviParshan we can use compile or api.

Dependencies appearing in the api configurations will be transitively exposed to consumers of the library, and as such will appear on the compile classpath of consumers.

Dependencies found in the implementation configuration will, on the other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into the consumers' compile classpath.

Comment: use ./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration implementation

Answer (score 18):

If the same error is on `appcompat`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
```

then adding `design` solved it.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
```

For me, adding

```
implementation 'de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:2.0.6'
```

was including `appcompat-v7:23.1.1` in

> .idea/libraries

without `vlc`, `appcompat` alone is enough.

Comment: Many thanks, it worked, but what is the role of 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'

Answer (score 15):

Another way to solve conflicts is just to force the correct version for all dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
            configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                    if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support' && details.requested.name == 'support-v4') {
                        details.useVersion "27.0.2"
                    }
                }
    ...
    }
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html

Comment: Dependency resolve rules are hard to maintain. They have to be maintained manually for version number and any change in implemented support libraries. For example Android Studio highlights newer lib versions available, but does not interpret these rules.

Answer (score 12):

Use support-v13 instead of support-v4

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0'
```

Comment: I am getting problem with this:compile    'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'

Comment: Exact same error as above:->  all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification Recyclerview

Comment: @Googli, Please write **compileSdkVersion**, **buildToolsVersion** and **dependencies**
I used this. No problem
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'`

`compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'`

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0'`

`compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'`

Answer (score 12):

add these in app level dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 9):

My problem is similar to yours.
Here exist an error!

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'`

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.3.0, 24.0.0. Examples include 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.0' and 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0'

Seeing this 
Examples include 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.0' and 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0'

the just add these codes in dependencies, make sure that versions are same.

```
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.0'
```

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error after adding `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'` with compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`.

Adding `animated-vector-drawable` and `mediarouter libs` fixed the issue.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 9):

I had  this:

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:12.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
   implementation'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
   implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
   implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
   implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
   implementation project(':vehiclesapi')
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

and got this error:
[image]

The solutions was easy - the primary dependencies were all correct so the leaves however - any third party dependencies. Removed one by one until found the culprit, and turns out to be facebook! its using version 27.0.2 of the android support libraries. I tried to add the cardview version 27.1.1 but that didn't work eithern the solution was still simple enough.

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:12.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
   implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'){
       // contains com.android.support:v7:27.0.2, included required com.android.support.*:27.1.1 modules
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
   }
   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1' // to replace facebook sdk's cardview-v7:27.0.2.
   implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
   implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
   implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
   implementation project(':vehiclesapi')
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I used these two to solve my problem after upgrading to android studio 2.3

```
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem before and I got the solution for it.

I just added the libraries that had the another version but with the same version of my `support:appcompat`.

For your error for example :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 25.1.1, 24.0.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.1 and
>   com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0

*The solution is to compile the versions of these libraries like that :

`compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.1.1'`

-if another library had the same issue and had another version just compile it with your `support:appcompat` version

This resolved my problem and I hope it resolves yours.

Best wishes :)

Answer (score 8):

After searching and combining answers, **2018 version** of this question and it worked for me:

1) On navigation tab change it to project view

2) Navigate to **[YourProjectName]/.idea/libraries/**

3) Delete all files starting with Gradle__com_android_support_[libraryName]

E.g: **Gradle__com_android_support_animated_vector_drawable_26_0_0.xml**

4) In your gradle file define a variable and use it to replace version number like **${variableName}**

Def variable:

```
ext {
    support_library_version = '28.0.0' //use the version of choice
}
```

Use variable:

```
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${support_library_version}"
```

example gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ext {
        support_library_version = '28.0.0' //use the version of choice
    }

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-ui:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-fragment:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${support_library_version}"

}
```

Comment: This answer needs more explanation.  A reader could be led to believe they should copy-paste your entire gradle file into their project.  You should explain why you added the extension and why you set some support libs to the gplaysvcs version, others to the supportlib version, and some are unchanged.

Answer (score 8):

### Very Simple with the new version of the android studio 3.x.

Just copy the version that is less than the current version and add it explicitly with same version number as current version.

**Example**

> Found versions 27.1.1, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0

Just copy the version `com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0` and change it to `com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1` so that it becomes equal to the current version you are using and add it to your gradle dependencies as following.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
```

**Note: Once you are done don't forget to click *Sync now* at the top of the editor.**

Answer (score 8):

I have faced this problem after upgrading to android studio 3.4 and sdk version to 28.0.0. Applying below dependency solved the problem for me.

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 7):

in 2018 update for this error add implementation from project structure

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
```

in project mode --> **External Libraries** there you can find your problem, in my case 
i am using version 28 and external libraries i found
`com.android.support:support-media-compat-26.0.0` and here was the error.

after implementation `support v13` and it's working

Comment: Red underline disappeared with this implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You have defined any other dependency to compile with version `24.0.0` instead of `25.1.1`. Please set all dependencies version the same as `25.1.1`.

Comment: I have updated my answer all the support versions has the same version 25.1.1

Answer (score 6):

I had to add the following lines in gradle to remove the error

```
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran ./gradlew tasks --all and checked for dependencies that were a different version from the targeted version (25.3.1). You'll get something like this:

```
app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library - Prepare com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library - Prepare com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72531Library - Prepare com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2531Library - Prepare com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2531Library - Prepare com.android.support:design:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72531Library - Prepare com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72531Library - Prepare com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72531Library - Prepare com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library - Prepare com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library - Prepare com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library - Prepare com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library - Prepare com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library - Prepare com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library - Prepare com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library - Prepare com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2531Library - Prepare com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
app:prepareComAndroidVolleyVolley100Library - Prepare com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0
app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers1312Library - Prepare com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.12
app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta124Library - Prepare com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.4
app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics267Library - Prepare com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7
app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore2316Library - Prepare com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.16
app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4161Library - Prepare com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.1
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4Impl1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1026Library - Prepare com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1026Library - Prepare com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1026Library - Prepare com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppindexing1024Library - Prepare com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.4
app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1026Library - Prepare com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1026Library - Prepare com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1026Library - Prepare com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.2.6
app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging1026Library - Prepare com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6
app:prepareComMindorksPlaceholderview027Library - Prepare com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.2.7
app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
app:prepareDebugDependencies
app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
app:prepareInfoHoang8fAndroidSegmented105Library - Prepare info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5
app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1316Library - Prepare io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.16
app:prepareNoNordicsemiAndroidLog211Library - Prepare no.nordicsemi.android:log:2.1.1
app:prepareNoNordicsemiAndroidSupportV18Scanner100Library - Prepare no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:1.0.0
```

In this case, I was targeting 25.3.1, and had some dependencies targeting different versions when I ran this command. The trick is to identify the dependencies in this list that are targeting previous versions, and overriding that by importing the most recent version of the dependency in Gradle.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my flow to fix this warning

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion ... // must same version (ex: 26)
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'any com.android.support... library'  // must same version (ex: 26.0.1)
    compile 'any com.android.support... library'  // must same version (ex: 26.0.1)

    ...
    compile ('a library B which don't use 'com.android.support...' OR use SAME version of 'com.android.support'){
         // do nothing 
    }

    ...
    compile ('a library C which use DIFFERENT 'com.android.support...' (ex:27.0.1) { 
        // By default, if use don't do anything here your app will choose the higher com.android.support... for whole project (in this case it is 27.0.1)

        // If you want to use 26.0.1 use
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: '...' (ex module: 'appcompat-v7') 
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'another module'
        ...

        // If you want to use 27.0.1 do 
        Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` and all 'com.android.support' to 27.0.1.
        (It may be a good solution because the best practice is always use latest `compileSdkVersion`.  
        However, use 26 or 27 is base on you for example higher library may have bug)
    }
}
```

**To** view/verify the `dependencies` of all library in your app
Open terminal and run `./gradlew app:dependencies`

**To** view the `dependencies` of a specific library in your app follow tutorial here :- [How to exclude dependencies of a particular dependency in Gradle](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-find-dependencies-particular-dependency-gradle-hesamedin-kamalan-1/)

Hope it help

Answer (score 6):

I have the same Problem but I solved this By adding 
those Three Lines

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1"
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
```

now Every thing Works perfectly

Answer (score 5):

Open the external library of your project you will see that some library still using previous version although you didn't mention those library so my suggestion is just use the particular library version for those it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I just update my Android Support Repository to (revision: 44.0.0);
then Android SDK tools and Emulator to latest version 25.3.1 from sdk manager> SDK tools
And it solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the error was a result of a third-party library that I imported that used older Google Support Library modules. I simply updated them to the latest version (checking on Github for example), and the error was gone. I suggest checking all the non-Google libraries that you included in your `build.gradle` are up to date.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue after updating to Android Studio 2.3, the fix was to add the following package in the `build.gradle`:

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'`

**Note:** Change the version to match other support library packages used in your project

Answer (score 5):

Make sure all Facebook SDK dependencies use the same support library version of your project:

```
dependencies {
    // Facebook SDK dependencies, excluding Bolts
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0"
    compile "com.android.support:design:25.4.0"

    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Highlight the error and press "ALT+ENTER", you'll see an option to:

Add Library dependency > Edit Intention settings

This will bring you to a menu where you'll see the specific problem support dependency that differs with support-compat. Create its dependency in gradle (com 'XXX') and set it's version to match that of support-compat. Sync gradle and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

after this line You have to add new Line in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Comment: You only need the second one. It includes the first on its own

Answer (score 4):

I got this problem after updating to Android Studio 2.3

Adding these lines in dependencies solved my problem

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'  
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

remplace this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
```

by this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
```

rebuild and good coding

Answer (score 4):

I had these dependencies in my project:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
```

So far nothing seemed wrong, but I got this message:

> Found versions 28.0.0, 23.4.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.

Then I did:

```
$ ./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath >> dep.txt
```

In the file, I searched for the *palette* and found that it was used by firebase storage:

```
\--- com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0
     +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
     +--- com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0
```

After adding:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
```

Seems resolved, and no more error.

//Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I managed to compile (not very clean) by adding

[image: image description here]

Answer (score 3):

Try To make the build tools exactly the same version of support library

example

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.itechnologyeg.*******"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    } 
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another thing that could cause this issue, is if you got declarations like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

That `+` means taking the latest version which might be a later version than the `25.3.1`. Replace the `+` with the specific version like `25.3.1` like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

and it will solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing problem after implementing all below mentioned new libraries. I was facing the above mentioned same problem on this `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'` compatible verions.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
```

I just replace 
this

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

to this

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
```

Comment: just adding implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0' works for me

Answer (score 3):

For me I resolved error by adding: `compile 'com.android.support:design:<version>'`

Answer (score 3):

include the following line:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Make sure you are using android studio plugin 3+

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be resolved using the following method:

1. Open your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
2. Click on the **Merged Manifest** option at the bottom
3. At the right side, it will show **Other Manifest files**. Here are the separate manifest files for the different dependencies that you included, or were included because of the effect of some other dependency.
4. Find out the dependency which is mentioned in your error message. Click on it to open its manifest file.
5. If your error message says to change the `android:value` attribute in the `meta-data`, then this is the place to do that change.
6. Change the value and other places where that unmatching version number appears and change it with the version that you included in the `build.gradle` file.
7. Now sync the project and you are good to go

Answer (score 3):

It just simple just force all v7 and v4 libraries to use the library version you have set just before your dependencies.

```
configurations.all {
                    // To resolve the conflict for com.android.databinding
                    // dependency on support-v4:21.0.3
                    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
                    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v7:28.0.0'
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.1.1, 24.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.1 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0

This warning usually happens when we're using Google Play Services because it's using support libraries as dependencies.

Most of us didn't know that **we can override the support libraries used in Google Play Services**. When we using the following dependency:

```
implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.1"
```

it implicitly depends on `com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.1.1`. But it is clashed with Google Play Service dependency which is `com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0`. So, we need to override it by explicitly using the library with:

```
implementation "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.1.1"
```

Then, your dependencies block will includes both of them like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.1.1"

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following lines in gradle to remove the error
this depends on the version you are using same as appcompat

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'

compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26+'
```

Comment: Use wildcard `+` for version is a bad practice. Always use exact version to have reproducible build.

Comment: Not recommended. Android Studio now even warns against wildcard versions.

Answer (score 1):

After spending about 5 hours, this solution worked for me..

First add this line to your manifest tag if you do not have yet:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.winanainc"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Then Add this meta tag inside your application to overwrite you build tools version, in this case for example I choosed the version 25.3.1

```
<application>
   ...
   ..
    <meta-data
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="25.3.1" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved
add following latest dependency`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'`

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way...and you have to manually do it...
go to build.gradle check assign all dependencies to same versions..
and it should work..

Answer (score 0):

Add the following implementation statements to the dependencies section. (If it shows some App Compat library mismatch error, then we have to re-implement all the mismatching support libraries. We can find the mismatching libraries by placing the cursor over the error. Press the shortcut key ctrl + F1 to reveal full details in android studio.)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score -3):

This error because of glide library. Try Picasso or other image libraries

Comment: nah bro its the answers above i can confirm as i had exact same error

Answer (score -4):

My solution i just add

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
```

and I build to test my app, everything is ok.

Comment: No, don't do this. this will make the ide error go away but your app may crash. they put this inspection for a reason!!