# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' when upgrade gms:play-services-auth to 10.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "APP_ID"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I don't understand why it is happening. I only know because using minSDK below 14 from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315548/problems-updating-new-version-10-2-0-of-playservices-and-firebase), but mine is 16.

Comment: It is likely that you have a dependency conflict here, you can print your dependency graph using "./gradlew dependencies" to show all the dependencies used in your project. My guess is you also need to update your firebase dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your firebase and Google Play Services dependency versions should match? Right now they're at 10.0.1 and 10.2.0

Comment: I feel so stupid right now, I thought because android studio only highlight gms to upgrade, I don't have to upgrade firebase. Thank you for your response.