# Getting error in adding dependencies for firebase-ui-auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

Since it is required to use FirebaseUI Version as per the Firebase/Play Services Version,
I am adding:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
```

and the only play services available for the app is:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
```

but Firebase UI libraries (1.2.0) still have a dependency on versions 10.2.0 of various play service libraries: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android.

These are the latest versions of all the dependencies, but it's failed to resolve in Studio.

Need some help!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try degrading 10.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Change

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'`

to

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'`

It works for me

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315548/problems-updating-new-version-10-2-0-of-playservices-and-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
```

These two work for me just fine. I'm not sure about the third one, though.