# can not use play-services-10.0.1

Tags: java, android, gradle

services-10.0.1 in android studio 3.0.1 in android O 
it throws an error with the fallowing text "Version must be at least 10.2.1 when targeting O". in android studio 2.3.3 it was working but when i update my android studio to 3.0.1 i got this error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adlift.adliftapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        testInstrumentationRunner                 
       "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }
       buildTypes {
        release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
      'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
        }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show your log cat

Comment: Why are you not using the latest version of the Play Services SDK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems updating new version 10.2.0 of PlayServices and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315548/problems-updating-new-version-10-2-0-of-playservices-and-firebase)

Comment: @NoumanCh in logcat i dont have any massages the error shows in the editor

Comment: @CommonsWare because in Iran people usually do not update their Play Services

Comment: Then presumably you will need to drop your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 25, to comply with the older Play Services SDK's requirements.